# In google App Engine can I create an online dev environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I would like to know how can i create a dev environment where I can deploy and test my application with other user and not locally.
Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you have a machine with a public IP address, you could just run the `dev_appserver` with the `-a publicIP` (you may also want to do `-p 80` to set the port to 80). You then can send your other users to that IP and it will be running the dev environment. If you don't have a machine with a public DNS, you could go the route of DynDNS or just get an Amazon EC2 box for as long as you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what feature do you want in "dev" environment. If you're referring to debugging, online GAE environment is not possible. However you can create a private project (with access only open to you and your colleagues) and use LOG/appstat to test it.

Comment: thank you, for the answers but maybe I didn't make myself clear :

Answer (score 0):

Why not just deploy your app? You can always set "login: admin" on all the pages if you only want certain users to use it.